# Django rq to do batch db insert

Tags: django, asynchronous, redis, long-integer, django-rq

How can I enqueue a function which will run a long time?

I want to do the following:

`def batch_insert(data):
    rows.append(MyModel(*data))
    if len(rows) > 1000:
      MyModel.objects.bulk_create(rows)`

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you have the `django-rq` app installed and registered in your project's `settings.py`. You will also need the following setting set:

   ```
   RQ_QUEUES = {
       "default" : { "USE_REDIS_CACHE" : "jobs" },
   }
   ```

   and the following added to your `CACHES` setting:

   ```
   CACHES = {
       ...
       {
           "jobs": {
               "BACKEND"  : "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
               "LOCATION" : "{{YOUR REDIS SERVER ADDRESS}}",
               "OPTIONS"  : {
                   "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a `jobs.py` file in your app, with the job you'd like to enqueue:

   ```
   from myapp.models import MyModel
   from django_rq    import job

   @job
   def batch_insert(data):
       rows = []
       rows.append(MyModel(*data))
       if len(rows) > 1000:
           MyModel.objects.bulk_create(rows)
       else:
           for row in rows:
               row.save()
   ```
3. Import your job into a view that triggers it

   ```
   from myapp.jobs import batch_insert

   trigger_batch_insert(request):
       sample_data = # Define your data here
       batch_insert.delay(sample_data) # This runs the job, instead of
                                       # running it synchronously
       return HttpResponse("Job running!")
   ```
4. Make sure you hook up the view to a URL route in your `urls.py`
5. Make sure your RQ workers are running:

   ```
   $ python manage.py rqworker default
   ```
6. Send the view a request, and check the console running the RQ workers to see if it worked :)